# Rails API POST (XML) - does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am trying to make a post request to remote API (external website), which accepts post parameters in XML form. I have the following code:

```
def advertiser_exists
      uri = URI.parse(@api_url)
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
      xml_string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><request><key>#{@api_key}</key><method>GetCampaigns</method><partner_id>#{@account_id}</partner_id></request>"
      request.body = xml_string
      request.content_type = 'text/xml'
      response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start { |http| http.request request }
end
```

But the response is not, what I would expect:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n\t\t\t<response>\n\t\t\t\t<status>ERROR</status>\n\t\t\t\t<reason>No Data</reason>\n\t\t\t</response>"
```

Here is the PHP version (supplied by the provider, which should work):

```
<?php
    // url api
    $url = "http://YOUR_URL/api/";

    // request
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <request>
        <key>abcdefghijklm</key>
        <method>AddConversion</method>      
        <partner_id>1</partner_id>
        <campaign_id>1</campaign_id>
        <conversion_id>1</conversion_id>
        <value>100</value>
    </request>';

    // sending request 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".$xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // response
    echo $output;
?>
```

Any idea, what is wrong with my code above (the parameters are correct and there should be data on response)?

Thanks, Miroslav